# Problem with Delegate and NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, delegates

I'm using a NavigationController  to "push" viewControllers from the rootView of an app.

I want to use delegates to comunicate the currently loaded view and the rootViewController. I was able to do this using NSNotificationCenter, but want give a try to delegates for this particular situation, since the communication is always going to be one-to-one.

In the view that is pushed, I declared the following delegate protocole in the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AnotherViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController {
    id <AnotherViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

- (IBAction) doAction;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end


@protocol AnotherViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) doDelegatedAction:(AnotherViewController *)controller;
@end
```

The doAction IBAction is connected to a UIButton in the view. In my implementation file, I added:

```
#import "AnotherViewController.h"    
@implementation AnotherViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction) doAction {
    NSLog(@"doAction");
    [self.delegate doDelegatedAction:self];
}
```

In my RootViewController.h I added **AnotherViewControllerDelegate** to the interface declaration:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <AnotherViewControllerDelegate> {...
```

and this to my implementation file

```
- (void) doDelegatedAction:(AnotherViewController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"rootviewcontroller->doDelegatedAction");
 }
```

Unfortunately it's not working. doDelegatedAction in the rootViewController is not been called. I suspect it's because of the way I push the AnotherViewController:

```
    AnotherViewController *detailViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

Should I tell, in any way, to AnotherViewController that its delegate is going to be RootViewController just in the moment it's been pushed? or am I missing something else?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `delegate`? You have to tell the instance of `AnotherViewController` which instance of `RootViewController` is its delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `delegate` of `AnotherViewController` to the `rootViewController` in order for everything to be connected up properly.

If you are initializing `AnotherViewController` in your `rootViewController` it would be:

```
AnotherViewController *detailViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```